# DTD to XSD migration of web.xml

Tags: xsd, dtd

I'm migrating my project from j2ee-1.3.jar to javaee-api-5.jar.

web.xml used to use http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd DTD for validation now it needs to use the XSD http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd

The original web.xml as usual fails with the current XSD,while trying to install in webLogic

I have following questions -
1. Do i need to compulsory do the correction of all the elements which are not correct according to the  new XSD basically servlet tags are rearranged or changed I guess.
2. Is it compulsory to have an XSD in web.xml, can I do away with the XSD definition and hence validation of the XML

Answer (score 0):

> Do i need to compulsory do the correction of all the elements which are not correct according to the new XSD basically servlet tags are rearranged or changed I guess.

Yes

> 2. Is it compulsory to have an XSD in web.xml, can I do away with the XSD definition and hence validation of the XML

No

**References**

- [XML 1.0 Schema: xml.xsd](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/errata01/os/schema/xml.xsd)